# Overwriting channels-config.xml on runtime

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex-mobile, parsley

I want to make dynamic modification of channels-config.xml whenever ip for services changed..I provided a screen to enable user to enter service ips on runtime but I don't tried this on any device. Will this work?

Note: The reason I'm using xml config is the use of Parsley framework...

Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via ActionScript. I don't think that's possible though, when the application is bootstrapped with a config, since a new configuration must be set up.

Comment: is it possible to rewrite something into config.xml after its packaged into .apk or .app file?

Comment: Well, theoretically. But you'd had to restart the application. If you use Parsley, create a class for the service to configure it. Then reconfigure or create new service instances when needed by manipulating the service's configuration object.

Comment: Ok I got you.. There's no problem if it needs to be restarted, do you have any examples or resources how to write into config.xml like that?

Comment: No sorry, i think i have a solution for the ActionScript example somewhere floating around though.